# SSL Certificate not working in chrome MVC

Tags: c#, google-chrome, model-view-controller, localhost

Hi i have followed the instructions to enable SSL for my web application as in this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

but when i run the application on google chrome it shows not secure, in internet explorer it works  fine. what is the problem with this ?

Comment: Are you running this locally or is this deployed? What is the detail of Google's "not secure" message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate)

Comment: yes running locally, details are: Attackers might be trying to steal your information from localhost (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID @MadMyche